# Jquery marquee and accordion clashing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a jquery marquee on my page, and also an accordion.

However with having both of them on a page the marquee stops working, the only library im using is jquery, could anybody tell me the best way to start debugging this?

thanks

Comment: hard to tell without any information at all. are there any javascript errors? which plugins are you using exactly? can you link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

If they both work individually, I would suggest finding another marquee plugin or pure javascript marquee.